# How to replace random match text from article using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, random, string-matching, replace

I'm sorry if this sounds silly, but I'm new with JavaScript, and what I would like to do is this:

Let's say I have some article with keywords inside, like for example "**training**". The article would be like:

> Some text here **training** and more bla bla bla. We can **training** this...
>   Using **training** you can...

Now what I would like to do is replacing "**training**" with let's say "**runing**", but I don't want them all replaced, I just want to replace one of them (a random one that is).

How can i do this using JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12604533/1250044

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small less 140byt.es function for this "problem": https://gist.github.com/3728254

**HTML**

```
<div id="str">Some text here training and more bla bla bla. We can training this... Using training you can...</div>
```

**JS**

```
var replaceR = function(a,b,c,d,e){e=new RegExp(b,"ig");a.innerHTML=a.innerHTML.replace(d?b:e,c)};

    replaceR(document.getElementById('str'), 'training', 'runing', false);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xvbvx/)

*UPDATE*

```
var string = document.getElementById('str').innerHTML,
    newString = string.replace('training', 'running');

document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = newString;
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/db3yc/

**UPDATE 2**

```
var s = "Some text here training and more bla bla bla. We can training this... Using training you can...",
    nth = 0,
    r = (new Date().getSeconds()) % 4;
s = s.replace(/training/g, function(match, i, original) {
    nth++;
    return (nth === r) ? "running" : match;
});
document.write(s);
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/JfYvA/

Comment: This just replaces all occurences.

Comment: I think you missed the key word of the question: "random".

Comment: im missing random part here, and it would be nice if html part would not be needed, just plain text to work with. Thank you

Comment: i see... It works here on demo, but when i put it to my test i get javascript error. Let me just tell you that this is not hosted, it is working solo, preparing articles for posting on my PC... if that gives you any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but after some small tests this should work :)

```
function replaceRandom(str, search, replace) {
    var split = str.split(new RegExp("\b?" + search + "\b?")),
        length = split.length - 1,
        rnd = ~~(Math.random() * length),
        result;

    if (length > 0) {
        result = split.map(function(val, idx) {
            return val && (val + (idx === rnd ? replace : search));
        })

        return result.join("").substring(-search.length);
    } else{
        return str;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARvcW/)

Comment: im not sure how to use this one :) sorry, but like said, im new to JS.

Comment: Means what? Any errors in the console? No replacement as in the example?...?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a function that builds a list of substring positions inside the main string and then performs a single random replacement:

```
function replaceRandom(str, needle, replacement)
{
    var indices = [],
    re = new RegExp(needle.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'ig');

    // find all string positions where needle occurs
    while (match = re.exec(str)) {
        indices.push(match.index);
    }

    if (indices.length) {
        // determine a random match to do replacement on
        var pos = indices[Math.floor(indices.length * Math.random())];
        return str.substr(0, pos) + replacement + str.substr(pos + needle.length);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

To call it:

```
var newStr = replaceRandom('Some text here training and more bla bla bla. We can training this... Using training you can...', 'training', 'running');
// newStr now contains a single replacement
```

Comment: @SomeoneWeird explain "not working", I've added the code to test it.